# ASP.NET code that inherits C#? Help needed

Tags: asp.net

This is at the top of an ASP.NET site I'm on working on.

```
<%@ Page Title="{ CompanyName } edited out for StackOverflow" Language="C#"
    MasterPageFile="~/fairway.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="index" %>
```

I'm wondering what the MasterPageFile portion does, what the CodeFile is for and why this apparent C# predicates this part after:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMeta" runat="Server">
    <meta name="description" content="edited for StackOverflow" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphHeader" runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .parallax-mirror { margin-top: -60px !important; }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/yottie/jquery.yottie.min.css" />

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphBanner" runat="Server">
    <uc:homebanner runat="server" ID="homebanner1" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphBody" runat="Server">
```

I'm trying to decipher where the header file is being pulled from to modify a navbar but the first and second parts are confusing. Any tips or big picture comments on what exactly is happening here would be much appreciated.

Comment: What research have you done so far? This is pretty standard ASP.NET WebForms information.

Comment: I'm trying to fix broken links, I've researched the broken links. This is a preliminary task. There is a broken link in the header. I need to know where the header file is allocated. I'm aware it's standard ASP code but could use some help to start so I don't have to ask my colleagues.

Comment: Look up some basic ASP.net **WebForms** tutorials for more in-depth info but here are the basics. *CodeFile* - The "Code Behind" page where programmatic logic goes, following separation of concerns. *MasterPage* - Where common page structure is maintained, also has a code behind page. The Nav Bar is commonly found in the Master Page.

Comment: Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/creating-a-site-wide-layout-using-master-pages-cs and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehszf8ax.aspx